# inclusion-exclusion principle proof (Without summations)

Tags: proof-writing

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$, and $\mathcal{C}$ are sets with $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} \cap \mathcal{C} = \emptyset$. Then $| \mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{B} \cup \mathcal{C} |$ = $|\mathcal{A}|$ + $|\mathcal{B}|$ + $|\mathcal{C}|$ Prove or disprove. If false, modify statement to make it true.

Comment: You are right that the given statement is false. "If false, modify statement to make it true" is exceedingly vague; there are an infinite number of ways to do that.

Comment: what would be one possible way? @bof

Comment: One way would be to change the hypothesis from $A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$ to $A\cap B=A\cap C=B\cap C=\emptyset.$ Another would be to change the conclusion to $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|$.

Answer (score 1):

For any three sets $$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|B\cap C|-|A\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|.$$
If $A\cap B\cap C=\phi$ then $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|B\cap C| -|A\cap C|\neq |A|+|B|+|C|. $

For example $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{2,3\}$ and $C=\{3,1\}$ then $A\cap B\cap C=\phi$ and 
$ |A\cup B\cup C|=3\neq |A|+|B|+|C|=6$